# Updating Service Fabric / VMSS storage account keys

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-vm-scale-set

When a new Service Fabric is created on Azure with a template, it uses this snippet of json -

```
"name": "[concat('VMDiagnosticsVmExt', '_', variables('vmNodeType0Name'))]",
"properties": {
  "type": "IaaSDiagnostics",
  "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
  "protectedSettings": {
    "storageAccountName": "[parameters('SupportStorageAccountName')]",
    "storageAccountKey": "[parameters('SupportprotectedAccountKey1')]",
    "storageAccountEndPoint": "https://core.windows.net/"
```

I want to update the storageAccountKey as part of our security procedures, but I can't work out how to change them.

I've tried applying the change via a template but I get the error

```
"code": "OperationNotAllowed",
"message": "VM Scale Set extensions of handler 
'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.ServiceFabricNode' 
can be deleted only at the time of VM Scale Set deletion."
```

And I can't find anything in PowerShell that will connect and let me change that

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the same template as the one you originally used to deploy Service Fabric? The error message sounds like only the scale set is specified in the template, and Service Fabric is blocking it because not including the service fabric extension in the template would remove service fabric from the scale set.

Comment: It was just the piece of template that was needed to change that setting - and it was incremental mode so it shouldn't be trying to change SF at all.

Comment: I've found ARM template system to be very finiky. Try pushing the original template with the changes applied.